# How to create an executable jar file (gradle 7.3, jdk17) without using plugins?

Tags: gradle, javafx

I learned how to create an executable jar file using **org.openjfx.javafx plugin**.

```
plugins {
  id('application')
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
  version = "17"
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.base', 'javafx.graphics']
}

dependencies {
  runtimeOnly 'org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.0.1:win'
  runtimeOnly 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.0.1:win'
  runtimeOnly 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.0.1:win'
  implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
  implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.14'
  implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.9'
}

mainClassName = 'default.Main'

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
    attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'default.Main'
    )
  }
  from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

Now the task is to build an executable jar file with a standard jdk and without javafx plugins.

I downloaded javafx modules.

**javafx.base.jmod**
**javafx.control.jmod**
**....**

I added these files to the resources folder in the project.

Created a file **module-info.java**

```
module default {
  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.fxml;
  requires javafx.graphics;
  requires javafx.base;
}
```

I have tried a lot of different examples of how to connect these modules using gradle (below is one of these).

```
compileJava {
  inputs.property('moduleName', moduleName)
  doFirst {
    options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath
    ]
    classpath = files()
  }
}


run {
  doFirst {
    jvmArgs = [
            '--module-path', 'C:\\Users\\insec\\Desktop\\piglet\\src\\main\\resources',
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls',
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.fxml',
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics',
            '--add-modules', 'javafx.base',
    ]
  }
}
```

But I can't run the application, the module-info file can't find jmods files.

How do I build a minimally working application, without using plugins, the entire configuration should be registered in gradle.

I am very confused by modularity in java 9, modularity in gradle and modularity in intellij idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do that. I and others seem to be answering this same question on an almost daily basis. The last answer is just 20h old. Why can't people not use the search function and go back just 24 hours?

Copied from previous answers:

Distributing JavaFX applications as fat jars is simply not very well supported. Have a look at JPackage instead. It comes with any recent JDK. And then maybe follow this tutorial: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: _I and others seem to be answering this same question on an almost daily basis_ well, you might consider voting to close as duplicate :)

Comment: So I put the question wrong, I don't need all the modules to be contained in one jar file.

Comment: That's why I downloaded javafx modules separately, I can't get my module-info file to see these modules.